# Swing MapPanel updating Graphics

Tags: java, swing, animation, jpanel

Trying to create a Panel with a graphical Map Overview. The Map overview shows 10x10 tiles of the complete map (so always only a certain area). This results in having 100 objects of MapTile, each representing one tile in the MapPanel class. each MapTile holds a Field object, which it is currently displaying. A field object saves a lot of data like if it is blocked, which person is standing on the field, which type the field is, etc. (possible types are grass, dirt, stone, etc.)

Whenever something changes i need to update the MapPanel so it shows the actual situation and not the one i instantiated it with. This is where i am currently failing.

This is what i have so far:

```
public class MapTile extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage backgroundImage;
    private BufferedImage fighterImage;
    private Field field;

    stuff...

    public MapTile(Field field) throws MidWarGeneralException {
        loadBackgroundImage(field.getType());
        if(field.isOccupied()) {
            loadFighterImage(field.getFighter().getTeam());
        }
        setToolTip(field);
        this.field = field;
    }

    private void setToolTip(Field field) {
        if(field.isOccupied()) {
            setToolTipText(field.getX() + "/" + field.getY() + "\n"
                    + "used by: " + field.getFighter().getName() + "(Team: " + field.getFighter().getTeam().getName()
                    + ")\n" + "Type: " + field.getType().getName());
        }
        else {
            setToolTipText(field.getX() + "/" + field.getY() + "\n" +
                    "Type: " + field.getType().getName());
        }
    }

    private void loadBackgroundImage(TileType type) {
        stuff...
    }

    private void loadFighterImage(Team team) {
       stuff ...
    }

    public void update(Field field) {
        this.field = field;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        g2d.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        if(fighterImage != null) {
            g2d.drawImage(fighterImage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }
    }
}
```

Both load() functions will just load the appropriate image based upon what current data the current field object has. What i want is: The MapTile object always has a background (grass.png, stone.png, etc.) and if the field is occupied by a person it will draw the person.jpg upon it in the team's color. This does work so far, however i fail at updating the view.

The view needs to update when:

1. We change the render area (the map could also be for example 200x200, but we always only render a 10x10 area of it. So we can "walk" in each direction and render a different region of the map)
2. A person moved (simply update the old and new field)
3. A person died (simply update the old field)

This is my MapPanel class:

```
public class MapPanel extends JPanel {
    private Map map;
    private int currentX;
    private int currentY;
    private List<MapTile> tiles;

    public MapPanel(Map map) {
        this.map = map;
        this.currentX = 0;
        this.currentY = 0;
        this.tiles = new ArrayList<>();

        init();
    }

    private int[] calcRenderArea() {
        currentX = (currentX > map.getWidth()) ? map.getWidth() : currentX;
        currentY = (currentY > map.getHeight()) ? map.getHeight() : currentY;

        int difX = map.getWidth() - currentX;
        int difY = map.getHeight() - currentY;

        currentX = (difX < 10) ? currentX - (10 - difX) : currentX;
        currentX = (difY < 10) ? currentY - (10 - difY) : currentY;

        return new int[]{currentX, currentY};
    }

    private void render() {
        int[] offsets = calcRenderArea();
        int tileCounter = 0;
        for(int x = offsets[0]; x < 10; x++) {
            for(int y = offsets[1]; y < 10; y++, tileCounter++) {
                tiles.get(tileCounter).update(map.getField(x + offsets[0], y + offsets[1]));
            }
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                MapTile tile = new MapTile(map.getField(i, j));
                tile.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(GUIConfig.BORDER_COLOR));
                add(tile);
                tiles.add(tile);
            }
        }
    }

    public void toLeft() {
        currentX -= 1;
        update();
    }

    public void toRight() {
        currentX += 1;
        update();
    }

    public void toTop() {
        currentY -= 1;
        update();
    }

    public void toBottom() {
        currentY += 1;
        update();
    }

    public void update() {
        // Todo :fix the map panel updating
        render();
    }
}
```

So i googled a lot so far and found a few posts about several images in a JPanel but none about how to update them... I tried so default repaint(); which doesn't work. Someone any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You need to change your program structure to more of an MVC (model-view-control) type structure, and have your view -- the GUI above, listen for changes to the model (the logical portion of your program) and update itself when changes occur.

Comment: Inside of your TilePanel's `render()` method's nested for loops, what happens if you call `tiles.get(tileCounter).repaint();` after calling `update()`  on the tile?

Comment: Exactly nothing happens. using tiles.get(tileCounter).repaint() will simply call repaint() which is what i already do in update()...

Comment: Indeed you're right, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to improve your MapTile's `update(Field field)` method such that it extracts all the information from the Field object similar to what your constructor does.

i.e.,

```
    public final void update(Field field) {
        // this.field = field;
        loadBackgroundImage(field.getType());
        if(field.isOccupied()) {
            loadFighterImage(field.getFighter().getTeam());
        }
        setToolTip(field);
        this.field = field;
        repaint();
    }
```

and

```
    public MapTile(Field field) throws MidWarGeneralException {
        updateField(field);
    }
```

---

But again as a "side" recommendation, a recommendation that won't solve your original problem but which will likely help solve future problems, I recommend that you change your program structure to more of an MVC (model-view-control) type structure, and have your view -- the GUI above, listen for changes to the model (the logical portion of your program) and update itself when changes occur.